# Laravel 8 with Ajax - 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

When I try type something in input it is throwing error **"405 Method not allowed"**. How can I fix this?

My route:

```
Route::get('/search' , [HomeController::class, 'searchPost'])->name('search-posts');
```

My blade:

```
<li><input id="search"  name="search" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="&#xF002; " type="text" style="border-radius: 100rem;font-family:Arial, FontAwesome"  >
```

My ajax:

```
$('body').on('keyup', '#search',function(){
            var searchQuest = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                method:'POST',
                url: '{{ route("search-posts") }}',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{
                    searchQuest: searchQuest,
                },
                success: function(res){
                    console.log(res);
                }
            });


        });
```

My controller:

```
public function searchPost(Request $request){
     
        $search_users = User::where('username','like', '%' . $request->get('searchQuest') . '%')->get();


        return json_encode($search_users);


    }
```

Comment: So `method:'POST'` is causing `Method not allowed` when you have `Route::get`?

Answer (score 2):

In your Route:

```
Route::get...
```

In your AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
          method:'POST',
          ...
```

The methods are differents, that's the error.

Comment: I changed Route::post instead of Route::get but now got this error '419 unknown status'

Comment: @232323quick2323 You also need to pass the csrf token from ajax.